# How to manipulate two json array ojects using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

This function

```
public function groups_priviledges($user_id = NULL){
    $data['groups'] = $this->priviledges_model->admin_groups();
    $data['member'] = $this->priviledges_model->empAdminGroup($user_id);
    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

has returned this json array on my browser

```
{
    "groups": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "description": "Human Resources",
            "added": "2018-06-21 16:27:20",
            "status": "1"
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "description": "Purchasing",
            "added": "2018-06-21 16:31:47",
            "status": "1"
        },
        {
            "id": "4",
            "description": "Warehouse",
            "added": "2018-06-21 16:31:47",
            "status": "1"
        }
    ],
    "member": [
        {
            "id": "41",
            "admin_group_id": "4",
            "employee_id": "16"
        }
    ]
}
```

I am having a serious challenge using ajax to list all the groups, and a checkbox checked only if a member belongs to a particular group.

My html currently looks likr this

```
<table class="table table-striped">
   <thead>
      <tr>
      <th> Priviledge </th>
      <th> Options </th> 
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody id="priviledges"></tbody>
</table>
```

And my ajax... I'm so lost here, doesn't return anything

```
<script>
$(function(){
    priviledges();

    function priviledges(){

        $.ajax({
            type: 'ajax',
            url: '<?php echo base_url() ?>users/groups_priviledges/<?php echo $tuser['employeeId'] ?>', 
            async: false,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data){
                var html = '';
                var groups;
                for(groups=0; groups<data.length; i++){
                    html += '<tr>'+ 
                                '<td>'+data[groups].description+'</td>'+
                                '<td>'+'<label class="check"><input type="checkbox" name="group[]" class="icheckbox" checked=""/>'+
                             '</tr>';
                }
                $('#priviledges').html(html);
            },error: function(){
                alert('Could not retrieve data');
            }
        });

    }
});
```

Thanks all in anticipation.

Comment: please provide your html structure and the ajax function.

Comment: Post your ajax & html code

Comment: Post is updated and now contains html and ajax, Thanks

Comment: "using ajax to list all the groups"...I think you mean "using _JavaScript_". AJAX is only used to make the HTTP request and retrieve the response. After that, the JavaScript code takes over. (I only mention this because it's always a good idea to understand and use the correct terminology to describe things, then people are not in any doubt about what you mean.)

Comment: noted aDyson... do you have a solution please?

Comment: @NsieSam yes, see my answer below

Comment: I forgot to say earlier, please stop using `async: false` in your AJAX call - you don't need it (you have used a callback function correctly when the data is returnd), also it gives a very poor user experience because the browser UI is frozen when the request is in progress (because JavaScript is single-threaded). Also most browsers have now deprecated it (for the above reason) so you'll see warnings in your console, and eventually it will stop working entirely. AJAX requests are intended to be asynchronous

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that `data` is an *object* which contains an array (stored within the "groups" property of the object). However when you write `data.length` and `data[groups]` you're treating `data` itself as if it were the array, which it isn't.

The solution is to refer to the `groups` property of the `data` object and then refer to a specific array item *within that*:

```js
var data = {
  "groups": [{
      "id": "1",
      "description": "Human Resources",
      "added": "2018-06-21 16:27:20",
      "status": "1"
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "description": "Purchasing",
      "added": "2018-06-21 16:31:47",
      "status": "1"
    },
    {
      "id": "4",
      "description": "Warehouse",
      "added": "2018-06-21 16:31:47",
      "status": "1"
    }
  ],
  "member": {
    "id": "41",
    "admin_group_ids": ["1", "4"],
    "employee_id": "16"
  }
};

var html = '';
for (var count = 0; count < data.groups.length; count++) {
  html += '<tr>' +
    '<td>' + data.groups[count].description + '</td>' +
    '<td>' + '<label class="check"><input type="checkbox" name="group[]" class="icheckbox"';
  for (var ids = 0; ids < data.member.admin_group_ids.length; ids++) {
    if (data.member.admin_group_ids[ids] == data.groups[count].id) {
      html += "checked=checked";
      break;
    }
  }
  html += '/></tr>';
}
$('#privileges').html(html);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th> Privilege </th>
      <th> Options </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="privileges"></tbody>
</table>
```

N.B. In the above I have also:

- corrected the spelling of "privilege"
- corrected the error in the definition of the `for` loop (`i` was not defined)
- changed the loop variable name to "count", so it's not confused with the "groups" property in the data.
- assumed that the JSON structure of "member" will now be changed to make sense when the member is in more than one admin group, and will be like this: `"member": { "id": "41", "admin_group_ids": ["1", "4"], "employee_id": "16" }` (see comments below)

Comment: Thanks so much @ADyson. I really appreciate your answer as it has been able to list but just the groups and explained a lot for me. However, the goal is for the checkbox to be checked by default if data.groups[count].id == data.member[count2].admin_group_id

Comment: @NsieSam Sorry I forgot about that part. Please see the updated answer now. P.S. If you are only returning one "member" item then it doesn't make much sense for it to be in an array. Or have I misunderstood? Will it return more than one "member" if the member is in more than one admin group? It's not clear.

Comment: thanks a great deal. It's working but it checks only the first element [0] even if member belongs to more than one group

Comment: @NsieSam So you're saying if they're in more than one group you'll get JSON like `"member": [{
    "id": "41",
    "admin_group_id": "4",
    "employee_id": "16"
  },{
    "id": "41",
    "admin_group_id": "1",
    "employee_id": "16"
  }]` ? This is unnecessary duplication of data, it doesn't really make sense. A more logical structure would be `"member": 
        {
            "id": "41",
            "admin_group_ids": ["1", "4"],
            "employee_id": "16"
        }`  Are you able to change the server to output it like that instead?

Comment: @NsieSam ...cont'd: Depending what structure you're going to use, I can amend the code so it uses a loop to check all the IDs of the member.

Comment: Ok. Thanks so much. Please do an amendment. I will be so grateful .

Comment: @NsieSam By all means. But first I need your answer to my question. Which structure for the member data are you going to use - your current structure or my suggested improvement? The code to read it will be different in each case.

Comment: @NsieSam take a look now, please. It's just another loop over an array really, nothing too complicated.

Comment: Thanks so much. still having issues getting this line tho  "admin_group_ids": ["1", "4"],

Comment: Thank you so much for your patience and dedication to ensuring you solved a problem today. It was awesome